# Why does the .exe fail after I enter text?

Tags: python, grammar

I do not know how to code, but I found code for a simple grammar editor and I plugged it into pycharm it works, but is perhaps too simple for what I need, but it's something workable. I made it into a .exe and ran it. The exe would allow me to put in text to be checked/corrected. But, unlike in the pycharm environment instead of making a correction it simply closes down. In the pycharm environment it seems to work, but the actual .exe fails after I hit enter.

The code is short.

```
from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt

Parser = GingerIt()

text = input("Enter the text to be corrected: ")


ct = Parser.parse(text)

print("The corrected text is:", ct["result"])
```

Comment: it seems like the key issue is the .exe, so knowing how you made the .exe will be important for anyone to be able to help. what tool did you use? what parameters did you use for that tool?

Comment: It's likely that the console window closes before you can see the output. Adding a `input("Press enter to exit")` after the final `print` might solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Scotscotmcc forgive me for my lack of knowledge. I used Pycharm, to create the .exe I ran the command pyinstall --name myapp --onefile myapp.py.

Comment: @Felipe Rodrigues. That has resolved my issue! It still closes after one correction so it must be ran each time a grammar check is needed.